# JQuery .load messing up HTML text styling

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I currently have a heading for my website which I created using:

```
 <div id="question">
  <h1>Question Goes Here</h1>
 </div>
```

The font is determined by my CSS and the size is h1.
The text there is very temporary, as I use a JQuery .load to change the font. The code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#question').load('/php/getQuestion.php',
      { name: 1} );
}
```

My site wide CSS is:

```
body {
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

And the relevant CSS for the page is:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The text requested loads perfectly, but the font isn't the one from my CSS and the size is 12 pt., not h1. How can I have the text load correctly after calling .load?

Comment: does that pag have any css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading the text into the container (i.e. DIV `#question`), not into the `h1` tag, therefore the different font size (I can't tell for the font itself, since you didn't post any CSS concerning that). That way the text will replace the whole `h1` including tag and contents.

You can use `$('#question > h1').load ...` as a selector

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
$('#question');
```

Is not the right selector. In your question you stated that you wanted the question in the h1, but above you place it in the div that is the *Parent* of the h1.

ie.

```
<div id="question"> // Your placing it in this div (the wrong one)
 <h1>Question Goes Here</h1>
</div>
```

Instead, consider changing the selector to:

```
$('#question > h1');
```

Which will instead select the *FIRST h1 ELEMENT* inside the #question div, which is the one you want